# How does mediawiki upload files to server

Tags: php, mediawiki

I just found out that mediawiki does not use [`move_uploaded_file`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file). So how does mediawiki upload file to the database?

Comment: I don't have the answer, so I won't bother posting an "answer", but try reading http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an incredibly complex system of filesystem classes in the `includes/upload` and `includes/filerepo` folders.  The relevant line, so far as I can tell, is line 216 of `includes/filerepo/FSRepo.php`:

```
if ( !rename( $srcPath, $dstPath ) ) {
```

If you really want to work out how the system works, I suggest you start with `includes/upload/UploadFromFile.php` and work your way through the network of objects.  If you want your sanity, I suggest you don't.

Comment: Great.. Thanks.. I din find the answer.. Just that I forgot to post to it here :)